# Calculating azimuth for shortest line from point to polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, azimuth

How can I calculate the azimuth for the shortest line from a point (start) to a polyline (end) in QGIS?

NNJoin calculates only the distance and joins the attribute from the line to the point attributes. Does QGIS have a function or plugIn for this?

Answer (score 1):

1. NNJoin find the nearest polyline
2. QGIS function `shortest_line` calculate the line between point and nearest polyline
3. QGIS function `azimuth` calculate the degrees for the shortest line